# playframework global callback for successful response

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I am using Play!Framework 2.2.x(Java) for communication between server and mobile app.

I want to get callback if the mobile app request data and it was successfully returned in controller's action.

Because I want to store last time the app successfully get the data from the server, so that I can only provide the data after that time if the app is not request specific time of data.

I looked at play.GlobalSettings, there are onRequest, onBadRequest, OnError, however I can't find onSuccess kind of global handler.

It would be very appreciated if anybody give me some ideas in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I did as follows on GlobalSettings#onRequest,

```java
@Override
public Action onRequest(Request request, Method method) {

    return new Action.Simple() {

        @Override
        public Promise<SimpleResult> call(Context context) throws Throwable {
            // TODO: do something before actual action call.

            Promise<SimpleResult> call = delegate.call(context);
            Callback<SimpleResult> callbackOnRedeem = new Callback<SimpleResult>() {

                @Override
                public void invoke(SimpleResult result) throws Throwable {
                    // TODO : do something after action call.
                }

            };
            call.onRedeem(callbackOnRedeem);
            return call;
        }

     };
}
```

Javadoc for onRedeem:

[http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0/api/java/play/libs/F.Promise.html#onRedeem(play.libs.F.Callback)](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0/api/java/play/libs/F.Promise.html#onRedeem%28play.libs.F.Callback%29)

Comment: I was going to use the [ActionsComposition](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaActionsComposition) approach, but found your solution and it worked well. 
Thanks.